# Making a Exponent parameter optional with a default value of 2

Tags: python

Currently I have my power function set up this way:

```
def power(base,exponent):
"""calculate the base raised to the power exponent"""
if exponent < 0:
    return base**exponent
elif exponent == 0:
    return 1
else:
    tmp = base
    for counter in range (exponent-1):
        tmp *= base
    return tmp
```

I need to make the exponent an optional parameter with the default value of 2, I'm unsure what I need to do from here any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you unsure?  The Python documentation and on-line tutorials seem quite clear.  What have you tried, and how did it not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you set optional parameters:

```
def power(base,exponent=2):
```

Note that all of optional must be after required ones.
You can list by order `power(3, 2)`, `power(3)`
But in case you have multiple optional parameters, you can specify using name without having to list all `power(3, exponent=2)`.